# Downloading file from SFTP and passing as response header has stopped working

Tags: node.js, express, sftp, content-disposition

I'm having a massive headache as a piece of code which worked perfectly fine for weeks has all of a sudden stopped working.

This is the code:

```
app.post('/scripts', (req, res) => {

    var remoteFilename = '/path/to/my/file.csv';
    var localFilename = 'newfilename.csv'

    sftp.get(remoteFilename).then((stream) => {

        res.set('content-disposition', `attachment; filename="${ localFilename }"`);
        stream.pipe(res);

    });

})
```

Quite simple - Fetches a file from my SFTP using node module ssh2-sftp-client, and pushes it back to the browser and automatically downloads the file. That's what it used to do anyway. Now it's just stopped working - I call the POST request and the browser just spins until it times out. The worst part is no error is thrown, and when I add a catch block still no error is shown.

I believe the only thing I've changed which might have an affect is I changed the

```
"engines": {
    "node": "6.x"
  }
```

to

```
"engines": {
    "node": "10.12.0"
  }
```

As cloud foundry was throwing errors with another part of my code and it linked back to the node version. But even when I switch it back it doesn't work. Does anyone have any ideas why it might no longer be working?

Many thanks,

G